# Wraaping HighCharts axis labels in a border box

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have used Highchart for one of my calendar based requirement to show events throughout the year. I have made various changes to basic `columnrange` graph.

However from the presentation point of view, I have still two points to accomplish:

1. Will it be possible to wrap the headers `(Jan, Feb, Mar ....)` in boxes, to give a `<thead>` kind of effect.I tried passing the html from label.formatters as below.
   `return '<div style="height:10px">Jan</div>'`

   But this didn't seem to do the trick. Applying css border or anything to this div does nothing.
2. I want to remove the extra bit of gridlines that comes out from top and bottom of the graph. How can I do that??

I have my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/btzqnfnh/1/) here. Have a look.

Comment: Set `useHTML` to true for the labels: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.useHTML, then you can style them however you want in your CSS.

Comment: In addition, you can remove this gridlines by changing your xAxis min and max: http://jsfiddle.net/btzqnfnh/4/

Comment: @jlbriggs: This was very close. However, I still am unable to achieve required view. Somehow when I place my `html` content. After a limit, it gets tilted, although there is space between two labels. I tried putting margin and padding 0. But still not working. Can u have a look. I am returning following from label.formatter:
`'<div style="border:1px solid black;height:20px;width:34px;margin:0;padding:0px">Jan</div>'`

Comment: @Grzegorz:  thanks that solves point #2

Comment: You can also set `rotation: 0` to your label settings to stop the auto-rotation

Comment: Well thanks @jlbriggs I put `rotation:0`, that solved the rest. U might want to have this as one of your answers though.